# Consecutive days reset for no reason

Tags: support

Yesterday, I looked at my profile and it said I had 25 consecutive days. Today I look and it has 1. That's wrong.

I'm also active on SciFi.SE. There I have 69 days consecutive. I check the two sites at the same time and in the same way. So how could I have 69 consecutive days on one and NOT have 69 consecutive days on the other. That is clearly a bug.

Comment: There could be several reasons. See [this question on Meta.Stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55394/why-did-my-consecutive-days-disappear).

Answer (score 3):

Your access history goes like this:

```
May 26 13:44:44 UTC
May 24 04:18:27 UTC
```

Note the timezone... [a "day" around here is measured in the UTC timezone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start).

It looks like you didn't access the site on May 25, so the day counter reset. Your SciFi account does show access on May 25. I'm not sure what you usually do when you visit different SE sites, so I don't know if that's what you did, but just opening the front page isn't necessarily enough to count as a visit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: After the first two times when the counter reset, I started the practice of, at least once per day, going into my profile page where it shows when I last accessed the site and how many consecutive days I've accessed it for. I was working from home that day, so I accessed the site several times. The history is wrong.